# Escaping JSON Data in POST

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

I am struggling to `POST` `JSON` to my localhost, using `Curl` from **`mingw64`**.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/csp-report;charset=utf-8' 
--data '{"csp-report":{"document-uri":"https://localhost/test",
"referrer":"https://www.google.com/",
"violated-directive":"default-src self","original-policy":"default-src self; report-uri /csp.php",
"blocked-uri":"http://evilhackerscripts.com"}}' 
'https://localhost/csp.php'
```

Testing some escaping suggested online, resulted into this output:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "referrer"
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "https
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "violated-directive"
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "default-src
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: self",
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "original-policy"
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "default-src
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: self;
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: report-uri
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ,"blocked-uri"
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 21:
```

**ERROR:** This is also what came up earlier. Works to POST from POSTMAN, but not via curl in Windows Command Prompt via mingw64

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'csp-report' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **11**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'document-uri' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **11**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'csp-report' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **12**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'referrer' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **12**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'csp-report' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **13**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'violated-directive' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp-reporter.php** on line **13**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'csp-report' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **14**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'original-policy' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **14**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'csp-report' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **15**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property 'blocked-uri' of non-object in **C:\www\testing\csp.php** on line **15**

Comment: How is the question related to PHP?

Comment: On my localhost, I have a `csp.php` which reads from `php://input`, and I get unescaped data in the output. While everything works when I send a `POST` from **postman**.

Comment: Judging from the output, the request does not even reach the server (not at least all of it). It's almost certainly a bash escaping issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should run the curl command in sigle line like this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/csp-report;charset=utf-8' --data '{"csp-report":{"document-uri":"https://localhost/test", "referrer":"https://www.google.com/", "violated-directive":"default-src self","original-policy":"default-src self; report-uri /csp.php", "blocked-uri":"http://evilhackerscripts.com"}}' 'https://localhost/csp.php'
```

Or, you can add a backslash after every line to tell shell that your command is not over:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/csp-report;charset=utf-8' \
--data '{"csp-report":{"document-uri":"https://localhost/test",
"referrer":"https://www.google.com/",
"violated-directive":"default-src self","original-policy":"default-src self; 
report-uri /csp.php",
"blocked-uri":"http://evilhackerscripts.com"}}' \
'https://localhost/csp.php'
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Didn't think about that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work! Weird. I am in Windows, no Linux or MAC!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, regular Windows CMD and mingw64 under the Git directory.

Comment: @JohnSmith CMD has very convoluted, not specially well documented and probably incomplete escaping techniques. I've seen questions in the past (which of course I'm unable to find right now) that went nowhere. As hint, the escape character is `^` but you'll have problems with double quotes.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I am closing this Question now. I will have to seek it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This little script called **post.sh** worked for me:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

US01='bar2'$1'@foo.com'
RE01='{"email":"'${US01}'","password":"111-111"}'

curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d ${RE01} \
  http://localhost:30025/signup
```

Call it like this:

```bash
./post.sh 51
```

Passing in a new number creates a new user on the server.

Sample run:

```bash
./post.sh 51
{"email":"bar251@foo.com","password":"111-111"}
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:30025...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 30025 (#0)
> POST /signup HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:30025
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 47
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 353
< ETag: W/"161-S6X2031k1pG3b1BJRvOfoUtgcW0"
< Date: Sun, 04 Jun 2023 17:33:15 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact 
{
    "uid":"baN8CUel91SAbno4h6qWudA4qIR2","email":"bar251@foo.com",
    "emailVerified":false,"disabled":false,
    "metadata": {
        "lastSignInTime":null,"creationTime":"Sun, 04 Jun 2023 17:33:15 GMT",
        "lastRefreshTime":null
    },
    "tokensValidAfterTime":"Sun, 04 Jun 2023 17:33:15 GMT",
    "providerData":[{
        "uid":"bar251@foo.com",
        "email":"bar251@foo.com",
        "providerId":"password"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting this Bash-script when the question is tagged [tag:windows] and [tag:cmd]? The issue here is the wrong use of quotes, [which](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498151) [has been](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15828662) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66836733) [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73671867) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035580) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62301184).