# Using Curl in the CMD To send a Discord webhook

Tags: curl, cmd, discord

I want to send a Webhook Using The CMD Command line Curl
However the command i made:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"content": "Posted Via Command line"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" discord-webhook-link
```

Returns This Message

> curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 24
>
> {"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}

Is there a way I can send a Discord Webhook message via the command Line?

Comment: It seems your request body (provided by `--data` flag) is in wrong format. Check what discord webhook wants.

Comment: The Discord Developer docs are not very clear
I do Know i need Json pramarters but code examples i found online
Do not work

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

the following syntax is working for me, maybe give it a try.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data "{\"content\": \"Posted Via Command line\"}" discord-webhook-link
```

Comment: Still working perfectly. Last part (discord-webhook-link" is not necessary, at least for a text message. Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 1):

Discord Webhook is the easiest way to send message to a discord, but it will send the message to one specific channel. You need to create a server, click on engine icon of the channel, go to integrations, create one webhook and copy  the URL of webhook.

You can "<@" + ID_User + ">" to mention someone if you have more users on the channel (ex: <@610973627472746>).

This command works on linux and mac to send message:

```
curl -i --trace-ascii - -X POST https://discord.com/api/webhooks/7842846283746/D3SxBhkaz7sCEO9X9OfII03aj-UWNnuNmUlSRpni0mxiBeszzevCSNhpWOFsOSHkGHVM -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"content": "Hello <@610973627472746>"}'
```