# cURL runs fine on cmd line but not with a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

How do i convert this cURL cmd into a batch script -

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://api.example.com \
--header "Authorization: Bearer token" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "email@email.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "email@email.com"},"subject": "Subject","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Body"}]}'
```

this is the error that i am getting -

```
[Running] cmd /c "c:\Users\sendMail.bat"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
'--url' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'--header' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'--header' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'--data' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.078 seconds
```

Comment: Enter it in a single, very long line and remove the `\ ` line separators: `curl --request POST --url https://api.example.com --header "Authorization: Bearer token" --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "email@email.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "email@email.com"},"subject": "Subject","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Body"}]}'`

Comment: You could probably, replace those end of line backward slashes with carets. It is also very important that when you save your batch file, you make sure that you do not save it as Unicode, use ANSI instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape a new line with a `^` instead of a `\` and for `--data` turn `'` into `"` and `"` into `\"`:

```
curl --request POST ^
--url https://api.example.com ^
--header "Authorization: Bearer token" ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--data "{\"personalizations\": [{\"to\": [{\"email\": \"email@email.com\"}]}],\"from\": {\"email\": \"email@email.com\"},\"subject\": \"Subject\",\"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\", \"value\": \"Body\"}]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You add cmd.
You just need to open a CMD window to execute your curl. 
And needs to all be on one line.
Those errors you are getting because it is trying to execute each line as a command.

```
cmd /k 'curl -X POST --url https://api.example.com -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "email@email.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "email@email.com"},"subject": "Subject","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Body"}]}';
PAUSE
```

When you are done testing, remove the PAUSE.