# hitting a PATCH REST API endpoint using curl

Tags: rest, curl

I am trying to hit a REST API through curl on windows cmd and curl.exe on powershell

Below is how my curl command looks:

```
  curl --insecure -g -v -o -X POST --header 'content-type:application/json' --header 'accept:application/json' --header 'Cookie:CTSESSION=<my ctsession>' --data                       
"[{"id":"90344","alertId":"xxxx","action":"CLOSE","assignee":"xxxx"}]" https://<web-sso url>
```

also tried using single quotes for request body as shown below

```
curl --insecure -g -v -o -X POST --header 'content-type:application/json' --header 'accept:application/json' --header 'Cookie:CTSESSION=<my ctsession>' --data '[{"id":"90344","alertId":"xxxx","action":"CLOSE","assignee":"xxxx"}]' https://<web-sso url>
```

but I get "status":400,"error":"Bad Request".

I think I am making some syntax error around the array [] in request payload.
Have also tried using """ in request payload and also \ "" but nothing worked.

Please help me in figuring out my mistake

### UPDATE:

Tried with below curl command

```
curl --insecure -g -v -o -X POST --header "content-type:application/json" --header "accept:application/json" --header "Cookie:CTSESSION=<my ctsession>" --data "[{\"id\":\"90344\",\"alertId\":\"afas\",\"action\":\"CLOSE\",\"assignee\":\"akash@ab.com\"}]" https://<websso url>
```

but getting following error

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

Comment: You need a filename after `-o`.

Answer (score 0):

For parameter in Windows never use `'`, always use `"`.   A `"` in  a parameter needs to be escaped, so try:

```
curl --insecure -g -v -o -X POST --header "content-type:application/json" --header "accept:application/json" --header "Cookie:CTSESSION=<my ctsession>" --data "[{\"id\":\"90344\",\"alertId\":\"xxxx\",\"action\":\"CLOSE\",\"assignee\":\"xxxx\"}]" https://<web-sso url>`
```

I did try on my localhost, to post to POST.PHP:

```
<?php
print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true));
```

I received following output (after removing the `-o` option):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90344
            [alertId] => afas
            [action] => CLOSE
            [assignee] => akash@ab.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Luuk. Tried using escape character but getting error. Please find the update section in my question. Please can you help.

Comment: I would expec it to work, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834238/curl-post-command-line-on-windows-restful-service) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797156/how-to-send-post-request-with-json-body-via-curl-from-windows-batch-script)